# Set ECG paper-like grid intervals (highcharts.js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to show an ECG result with highcharts which is basically a simple line/spline diagram but with a little tweak. The ECG paper looks like this: https://cdn.printablepaper.net/samples/ECG_Paper.png

And this is what I want to achieve with hightcharts too. One little square means 0.1 mV and 0.04 s, so one big square is 0.5 mV and 0.2 s. I know there is a tickInterval setting, but that just does not work in this scenario, I think the intervals are too small for it, because it randomly hides grid lines.

The optimal solution would be that if there is a need for hiding grid lines (too broad data), it only hides the small squares. To try not to confuse the users with this, we also would like to colorize grid lines differently, so every fifth line should be red, others gray.

Is this possible with highcharts?

Comment: Have you tried to use **minor ticks**?: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6dbnmyxf/

Comment: That is not a bad idea, but there are cases, when on the X axix minor ticks are shown, but on the Y they are not (or inverse of this). How can I change this behaviour, so either both axis' minor ticks are on, or both off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minorTicks` functionality seems to be ideal for this case. Use this option along with `minorTickInterval`. Configuration for both axes will look like this:

```
var axesOptions = {
  tickInterval: 0.5,
  minorTicks: true,
  minorTickInterval: 0.1,
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  gridLineColor: 'red'
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6dbnmyxf/

If minor ticks are not visible on any axis this code will hide them on all axes (and restore them when needed):

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {

        var axes = this.axes,
          showMinorTicks = true;

        // find if minor ticks are present on both axes
        axes.forEach(function(a) {
          console.log(a.minorTicks);

          if (Object.keys(a.minorTicks).length === 0) {
            showMinorTicks = false;
          }
        });

        // hide/show ticks
        axes.forEach(function(a) {
          for (var key in a.minorTicks) {
            var mt = a.minorTicks[key].gridLine;
            showMinorTicks ? mt.show() : mt.hide();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

---

**API references:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minorTickInterval
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minorTicks

Comment: awesome, this render magic is exactly what I needed, thanks :)